# Andengine LWP screen orientation issue

Tags: java, android, andengine, live-wallpaper

I'm really stuck on the screen orientation logic.

Here is my code:

```
@Override
public EngineOptions onCreateEngineOptions() {
        this.cameraWidth = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
        this.cameraHeight = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
        this.camera = CameraFactory.createPixelPerfectCamera(this, this.cameraWidth / 2.0F, this.cameraHeight / 2.0F);
        this.camera.setResizeOnSurfaceSizeChanged(true);
        this.dpi = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi;

        Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
        int rotation = display.getRotation();
        if (rotation == Surface.ROTATION_90 || rotation == Surface.ROTATION_270) {
                screenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE_SENSOR;
        } else {
                screenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.PORTRAIT_SENSOR;
        }

        EngineOptions engineOptions = new EngineOptions(true,screenOrientation, new FillResolutionPolicy(), this.camera);
        engineOptions.getAudioOptions().setNeedsSound(true);
        return engineOptions;
}

@Override
public void onSurfaceChanged(final GLState pGLState, final int pWidth, final int pHeight) {
        super.onSurfaceChanged(pGLState, pWidth, pHeight);

        Log.i(TAG, "onSurfaceChanged " + "w: " + this.camera.getSurfaceWidth() + " h: " + this.camera.getSurfaceHeight());

        this.cameraWidth = this.camera.getSurfaceWidth();
        this.cameraHeight = this.camera.getSurfaceHeight();
        this.camera.setCenter(this.cameraWidth / 2.0F, this.cameraHeight / 2.0F);

}
```

When I try my LWP on AVD 3.7 FWVGA slider 480x854 everything works fine, **but only in the LWP preview mode**. When, for example - from the Landscape LWP preview mode I press button "Set wallpaper" I'm getting half black screen with my shifted LWP to the other half of desktop.

Also, I have noticed that method onCreateEngineOptions is not called when we returning from the Previos mode to the desktop.

Also, everytime I correctly receive onSurfaceChanged event in my LWP. Also, I have configured and can handle screen orientation change event... But how to apply it to my logic ?

```
public BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent myIntent) {

        if (myIntent.getAction().equals(BROADCAST_CONFIGURATION_CHANGED)) {

            Log.d(TAG, "received->" + BROADCAST_CONFIGURATION_CHANGED);

            if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
                Log.i(TAG, "LANDSCAPE_SENSOR");
            } else {
                Log.i(TAG, "PORTRAIT_SENSOR");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How to correctly setup LWP to handle both of modes - Portrait and Landscape ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I have similar problem with a game, I fix the problem with this line in each activity in the manifest file:

```
  <activity
        ....
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        ... />
```

and use the methods:

```
        @Override
public void onResumeGame() {
super.onResumeGame();

}

@Override
public void onPauseGame() {
super.onPauseGame();

}
```

hopefully solve your problem, best regards.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I already have <activity            android:name=".WallpaperSettings"            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" and this way LWP works perfectly with orientations in the preview mode. But LWP is a service and I can't provide android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" to it. I have created BroadcastReceiver inside of my LWPService and this way I can get orientation changes events.. but how to use it ? Also, could you  please tell me in more details how I can use onResumeGame()/onPauseGame() there ? Thanks, Alex